# Output does not emit the event

Tags: angular

I'm trying to do some simple `@output`, which are:

```
@Output () clickEvent = new EventEmitter <MouseEvent>();
@Output () blurEvent = new EventEmitter <MouseEvent>();
@Output () keypressEvent = new EventEmitter <InputKeypressEvent>();
```

However, none of them are sending an event and there is no `error` on the console.

I really don't know if what is happening, try to start an instance of EventEmmiter in OnInit when showing where it currently is, but it doesn't change at all.

My child component is not sending the @output event to the parent component, why is this happening?

**Child Component:**

```
<input
    [attr.style]="style"
    [attr.type]="type"
    [attr.placeholder]="placeholder"
    [attr.alt]="alt"
    [attr.value]="value"
    [attr.maxlength]="maxlength"
    [attr.readonly]="readonly"
    [attr.required]="required"
    (click)="(onclick)"
    (blur)="(onblur)"
    (keypress)="(onkeypress)"
/>


import { Component, OnInit, Input, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
import { InputKeypressEvent } from './input.interface';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-input',
    templateUrl: './input.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./input.component.scss'],
})
export class InputComponent implements OnInit {
    @Output() clickEvent = new EventEmitter<MouseEvent>();
    @Output() blurEvent = new EventEmitter<MouseEvent>();
    @Output() keypressEvent = new EventEmitter<InputKeypressEvent>();
    @Input() style: string;
    @Input() type: string;
    @Input() placeholder: string;
    @Input() alt: string;
    @Input() value: string;
    @Input() maxlength: string;
    @Input() readonly: string;
    @Input() required: string;

    constructor() {}

    ngOnInit(): void {}

    onclick(event: MouseEvent): void {
        this.clickEvent.emit(event);
    }

    onblur(event: MouseEvent): void {
        this.blurEvent.emit(event);
    }

    onkeypress(event: KeyboardEvent): void {
        this.keypressEvent.emit({ evt: event, value: this.value });
    }
}
```

**Parent Component:**

```
    <app-form [autocomplete]="'off'" [padding]="'0 1.3rem'">
        <app-input
            [style]="'border-stack-big'"
            [type]="'text'"
            [placeholder]="'Type a message'"
            [alt]="'Type a message'"
            [maxlength]="200"
            [required]="true"
            (clickEvent)="tst($event)"
        ></app-input>
    </app-form>

import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-send-message-container',
    templateUrl: './send-message-container.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./send-message-container.component.scss'],
})
export class SendMessageContainerComponent implements OnInit {
    isClicked = false;

    constructor() {}

    ngOnInit(): void {}

    tst(event): void {
        console.log('AQUIII');
        console.log(event);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your syntax is wrong for calling methods in your component that emit the events. Here it is corrected:

```
<input
    [attr.style]="style"
    [attr.type]="type"
    [attr.placeholder]="placeholder"
    [attr.alt]="alt"
    [attr.value]="value"
    [attr.maxlength]="maxlength"
    [attr.readonly]="readonly"
    [attr.required]="required"
    (click)="onclick($event)"
    (blur)="onblur($event)"
    (keypress)="onkeypress($event)"
/>
```